# How to install Windows 8 Installation ISO when it does not fit on a DVD?

Tags: windows, iso-image, windows-8-preview

I am trying to install the windows 8 64-bit ISO with developer tools. The ISO file is apparently 5.2GB when I try to burn it to my DVD, but the DVD's capacity is only about 4.8GB. In addition, I don't have any USB flash drives larger than 1GB. I have a bunch of DVDs, though. How can I install Windows 8 onto my computer without having to go buy DVDs with more space?

NOTE: I am not interested in the version without the dev tools.

UPDATE: I just realized I have a 1TB HDD! But I'm not sure how to install with that...

Comment: Have you got a USB key you can install from?

Comment: I have a 1GB USB flash drive, and a 512MB. But nothing larger.

Comment: I just realized I had a 1TB external hd this whole time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intended way of doing this, is burning the ISO on a dual-layer DVD. I assume you don't have one of those. Luckily, there is a lot of other ways of getting there.

I did read your note, but you can install the version without the dev tools, and then get the [full VS 11 preview from here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543). (the one included on the Win8 DVD download is just an express version, you can try the full version). This might be the easiest way to do it.

Another way would be to download both versions (with and without Dev Tools). Then burn the version without tools onto a DVD, and copy the files on the other DVD to your HDD (on a partition you will not install onto). Boot on the DVD, get to the recovery command prompt, then execute Setup.exe from the copy you copied to the HDD.

One way to get a command prompt is to press Shift+F10 on the screen where you should select the disk to install to (Shift+F10 probably works on the other screens too, haven't tried it though). Then just shift to the directory where you placed the install files and execute setup.exe. Depending on the location, it could be:

```
> D:
> cd Win8Install
> setup.exe
```

Btw, be aware that drive letters might have shifted in this environment. If the files is not on the drive letter you expected, just try looking through the disks starting from drive C:

Comment: but how do I get to the recovery command prompt, and how do I execute setup once im there?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: i have already installed windows 8 (wo dev tools). Would this still work if I select the win8 partition as the one to install to? I assume it would just format it...

Comment: Just choose to format it before installing (it's an option on the screen). But consider simply installing the VS 11 preview from here, you will get a larger version than the one on the DVD: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543

Comment: i would do that, but the dev tools has more than just VS.

Comment: it isn't working: when i run setup.exe from the recovery console, it shows the right window (it says "install now") but when i click install now, the window disappears and reappears without changing, its still at the "install now" window.

Comment: confirmed, the command prompt method doesnt work - running the setup from hard disk continues with the non-developertools installation

Answer (score 0):

If this is your Primary PC, then I would not recommend you to install Windows 8 directly on it.  I would suggest you to go for Virtual environment.  I have tried Virtual Box based setup and it works fine.

HowToGeek has written a detailed post on the same:
http://www.howtogeek.com/74515/how-to-test-drive-windows-8-in-virtualbox/

Hope this helps.

Comment: it did help, but unfortunately, I don't have enough RAM to have Windows 8 run smoothly this way.